# How to make Java program as platform independent exe?

Tags: java

Is it possible to run Java program without JVM?  How to make Java program as platform independent exe?

Comment: An "exe" is not platform independent. It will only run on Windows.

Comment: well, I guess you cannot do so, to run java you need jvm.

Comment: if you simply want to make an exe from jar file to  run java programs without jvm you can use exe4j, that makes exe file from java bytecode

Comment: Not only is an "exe" not platform independent in that it only works on Windows, it's not even guaranteed to do that.  .EXE is also one of the DOS executable formats (not compatible with Win32).  And a .EXE file for Windows NT running on, say, DEC Alphas won't work on an x86 Windows machine.  Further, .EXE is an executable extension on other operating systems as well -- **surprise!** -- those aren't cross-compatible either.

Comment: See also [how to make java program as platform independent exe](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2209070) at OTN.

Answer (score 3):

Even if with "exe" you don't literally mean a Windows executable program, a "platform-independent executable" doesn't exist. Native, executable programs are always platform-dependent.

The idea of platform independence in Java means that you can run compiled Java class files on any operating system that has a compatible Java virtual machine installed. Without the Java virtual machine, there is no way to run your Java program.

There is software that can convert Java class files into an executable which doesn't require the JVM to be pre-installed on a user's system. Howver, those executables will not be platform-independent.

There are also programs that can create a platform-specific installer for your Java program that will automatically download and install the JVM if the user doesn't already have it.

Answer (score 0):

answer 1: AFAIK no

answer 2: What is a platform independent exe? .exe files are very platform dependent, as they run on windows only (even though they can be emulated on Linux). If you want to have platform independence that's java's and jvm's ballcourt.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to run java program
>   without jvm?

**No**

> how to make java program as platform
>   independent exe

**exe** files are only for windows not for linux. You should build jar file which will run on windows and linux both.

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility JLCA from Microsoft to convert Java applications to C#.

I have tried it years ago, it seems like only support Java 1.4, so I don't know if there's any new release which can support generics.

See: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=46bea47e-d47f-4349-9b4f-904b0a973174&displaylang=en

I did also wrote a helper utility to remove type variables from existing Java 1.5+ sources, but since I haven't used it for years, I'm not sure if it still work.

See: https://github.com/lenik/jazz/tree/master/bas/layer-7/bas-dotnet-synthetics (Well, this is a support library, the main program is in my usb disk home, I haven't push to github yet.)